# Why doesn't traefik find the project?

Tags: docker, traefik

I have a laravel project running through docker containers. One of the docker containers is a traefik, but when I try to run the `docker-compose up` command, it returns a single log: `msg="Failed to read new account, ACME data conversion is not available : permissions 755 for acme.json are too open, please use 600"`. I tried to change permissions for asme.json on my ssh, but even after `chmod 600 acme.json` it returns this log again. On top of that, when I try to connect to the site via https, there is an error `404 page not found`, I got a similar error when I set up the nginx container, because I incorrectly specified the path to the project, but I don’t know what to do now. There are my
**1)traefik.tom**

````
logLevel = "ERROR"
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
      [entryPoints.http.redirect]
      entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
  [entryPoints.https.tls]
[api]
[ping]
# Enable Docker configuration backend
[docker]
network = "nginx-proxy"
domain = "mysite"
watch = true
exposedByDefault = false
[acme]
email = "my@gmail.com"
storage = "acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
onHostRule = true
caServer = "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
   [acme.httpChallenge]
   entryPoint = "http"
  [acme.dnsChallenge]
  provider = "cloudflare"
  delayBeforeCheck = 0```

And 2) docker-compose.traefik.yml

---
version: "3.6"

networks:
  default:
    name: nginx-proxy
    external: true

services:
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v1.7.14"
    container_name: ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}.traefik
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    expose:
      # traefik dashboard port
      - 8080
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`mysite`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.tls.certresolver=cloudflare"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.service=api@internal"
      - "traefik.http.services.traefik-traefik.loadbalancer.server.port=888"
      - "traefik.port=8080"

    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./docker/traefik/traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml
      - ./docker/traefik/:/acme.json
    environment:
        - CF_API_EMAIL=myapifemail
        - CF_API_KEY=myapikey
````

Answer (score 1):

based on what I see, you are using a volume to store the acme certificates as described [here](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/https/acme/#storage). But it seems you misread the volume binding and wrote

`- ./docker/traefik/:/acme.json`

instead of

`- ./docker/traefik/acme.json:/acme.json`

Doing so the folder is mounted as a file and end up with wrong permissions. Correcting the line should make it works.

Comment: Thank you so much. In my case I was using `.acme.json:/acme.json` and the fix was adding a slash `./acme.json:/acme.json`